# Macbook или Ноут + linux?

Tags: python

Углубляюсь в нишу Web Crawling. Собственно по небольшим стеснением обстоятельств нужен ноут. Что удобнее было бы при работе в этом направлении, Mac или ноутбук обычный с OS LINUX? У кого имелся опыт работы на обоих. Стоит ли переплачивать за MacBook?

Comment: Таким вопросам место на Тостере, все-таки. А данный вопрос смутно подходит под программирование. P.S. от себя - если финансы позволяют, то купите лучше мак - будет меньше геморроя и комфорта, имхо.

Comment: Сижу 3 года за маком - хороший коммерческий UNIX. Стоил бы в 3 раза дешевле - цены не было :) Собственно понятно, почему он так стоит, во всех странах есть свое представление сколько должен стоить приличный компьютер, в США на рынок которого ориентирована Apple, это 3000$. Для нас это перебор. Вам программировать? Используйте любой linux-дистрибутив, если возьмете какой-нибудь человечески дистрибутив, вроде ubuntu, так команданя строка и процесс работы даже удобнее.

Comment: Cпасибо! Да, ubuntu мне уже становится по душе. Сложновато пока что в терминале, но вот так и хочеться его открыть) Что-то в нем есть магическое)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Каждому своё, однако лучше не переплачивать за мак и сделать всё по человечески под себя на каком-нибудь дешевеньком ноуте